# Is there a way to make a "Not a number" if statement in Python?

Tags: python, input

Forgive me if this a stupid question, but I searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer due to the wording of the question.

Is there a way to have a "Not a number" value in an if statement in Python?

Say for example you have a menu like this:

```
For free examples - Press 1
For worse free examples - Press 2
```

And I wanted to write an if statement, or elif statement, that says something along the lines of:

```
elif menu_Choice != #:
    print("This menu only accepts numerical input. Please try again.\n")
    menu_Choice = input("\n")
```

Can I do so? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not say something like:

```
if menu_choice == "1":
    do this
elif menu_choice == "2":
    do this
else:
    print("Invalid input...!")
```

You could also do:

```
menu_choice = ""

while menu_choice not in ["1", "2"]: # not ideal with lots of choices
    print("This menu only accepts numerical input. Please try again.\n")
    menu_Choice = input("\n")
```

Then go to your if statments

**EDIT:**

with regards to your comment, you could do:

```
# you could make range as big as you like..
choices = [str(i) for i in range(1, 11)] #['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

while menu_choice not in choices:
    print("That input wasn't valid. Please try again.\n")
    menu_Choice = input("\n")
```

I made the list `choices` with a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: The second one works much better for what I have in mind, however if I have say, 10 numbers, is there a shorter way to condense it rather than list 10 numbers in quotation marks?

Answer (score 4):

There is the [`.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) string method.

```
elif not menu_Choice.isdigit():
    print("This menu only accepts numerical input. Please try again.\n")
    menu_Choice = input("\n")
```

Keep in mind this doesn't check if it's in the right range, just if it's numeric. But by the time you've gotten this far, maybe you could just use `else`?

Answer (score 1):

feeding of the other answer

```
choices = {
  "1": free_samples_list,
  "2" : other_list,
}
choice = input(...)
while choice not in choices:
     print ("Invalid choice:")
     choice = input(...)
```

this allows you to encapulate both data validation and selection